# Переименование окон и вкладок эмулятора терминала

Tags: debian

В Debian 8 (Jessie) возможно ли изменять названия окон (вкладок) на произвольные значения? Интересует прежде всего Terminal и его вкладки.

На данный момент контекстные меню для вкладок и для окон (`Alt+Space`) не содержат подобных действий, хотя в Ubuntu же, например, возможность переименования вкладок терминала имелась.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

многие реализации эмуляторов терминала для *x-window system* перехватывают *escape*-последовательность [такого вида](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-3.html):

```
\x1b]0;заголовок для окна и иконки\x07
\x1b]1;заголовок только для иконки\x07
\x1b]2;заголовок только  для  окна\x07
```

и устанавливают заголовок окна и/или иконки в панели задач.

отправить последовательность можно, например, программой *echo*:

```
$ echo -e '\x1b]0;заголовок для окна и иконки\x07'
```

---

значения символов "escape" (шестнадцатиричное `1b`) и "bell" (`7`) можно задать и в восьмиричной форме: `\033` и `\007`.

Answer (score 2):

Решил упростить это дело с помощью простого скрипта, предложенного [Александром Баракиным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/alexander-barakin).

- Создаём в каталоге, где у вас хранятся пользовательские скрипты, например в `$HOME/scripts`, данный скрипт:

  wname.sh:

  ```
  echo -ne "\E]0;$1\a"
  echo "Заголовок закладки изменён на '$1'"
  ```
- Делаем его исполняемым: `chmod +x wname.sh`
- В `~/.profile` добавляем пути к скриптам, если их не было:

  ```
  export PATH="$HOME/scripts/:$PATH"
  ```
- В `/usr/local/bin` создаём символьную ссылку на данный скрипт:

  ```
  sudo ln -s ~/scripts/wname.sh wname
  ```

Теперь вызовом команды: `wname "Какое-то новое название"` можем легко изменять название закладки терминала.